# How to call a class function which is not in interface in java

Tags: java, function, class, object, interface

```
interface MyInterface{
   public static int num = 100;
   public void display();
}
public class InterfaceExample implements MyInterface{
   public void display() {
      System.out.println("This is the implementation of the display method");
   }
   public void show() {
      System.out.println("This is the implementation of the show method");
   }
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      MyInterface obj = new InterfaceExample();
      obj.display();
      obj.show(); // how can i call this ?
   }
}
```

Above is some lines of code , I wanted to know can I call show() method of InterFaceExample class using interface object?.
Please help.

Answer (score 3):

You have three options.

1. Add the `show` method to the interface.
2. Change the type of `obj` to `InterfaceExample`.
3. Cast `obj` when you want to use a method that's only in `InterfaceExample`, for example `((InterfaceExample) obj).show();`

The third option here throws an exception if `obj` happens not to refer to an object of type `InterfaceExample`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an InterfaceExample reference and not a MyInterface reference.  The clean way to achieve that is to not assign the InterfaceExample reference to a MyInterface variable; you're throwing type information away.  Use an InterfaceExample variable instead.

Alternatively,if there's some reason you have to have a MyInterface variable, then you can cast to an InterfaceExample.  You may or may not need to handle the possible resulting exception.